# Interface doesn't come up in docker run

Tags: networking, docker

I'm starting a docker container with my own network configuration:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run --net=none --lxc-conf="lxc.network.type=veth" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4=10.0.0.100/24" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4.gateway=10.0.0.1" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.link=br0" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.name=eth0" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.flags=up" -i -t --rm centos /bin/bash
```

But as you can see, `eth0` doesn't up at all:

```
[root@70a7109e7ecd /]# ip addr list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@70a7109e7ecd /]# exit
exit
```

Note, `br0` has been well configured.